# internal.S3AbortableInputStream on hadoop fs -get s3 to EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, emr

When I ssh onto an EMR cluster and do the following command:

```
hadoop fs -get s3://path/to/my/files
```

I am getting the following error, and the file transfer fails partway through. I have used this command in the past, so I'm not sure what's up. Could it be related to the files' encryption? What would cause the stream to consistently close?

```
WARN internal.S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:253)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.closeStream(IOUtils.java:261)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination$TargetFileSystem.writeStreamToFile(CommandWithDestination.java:478)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyStreamToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:395)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyFileToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:248)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:317)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.recursePath(Command.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.recursePath(CommandWithDestination.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.recursePath(Command.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.recursePath(CommandWithDestination.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:289)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPathArgument(CommandWithDestination.java:243)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processArguments(CommandWithDestination.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:201)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:251)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: Not enough space on the cluster for the files.